# Conditions ensuring that $(t,x)\mapsto S(H(t,x),x)$ is a flow whenever $(t,x)\mapsto S(t,x)$ is.

Tags: operator-theory, functional-equations, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $\mathbb{R}_+:=\left[0,\infty\right)$, and let $S:\mathbb{R}_+\times X\to X$. We assume that $S$ is continuous with respect to each variable and has the flow property, i.e. $$S(0,x)=x\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;S(t+s,x)=S(t,S(s,x)).$$

Further, let $\lambda:X\to \left[m,M\right]$ (where $0<m<M<\infty$) be a continuous function. Now consider $L:\mathbb{R}_+\times X\to \mathbb{R}_+$ given by

$$L(t,x)=\int_0^t \lambda(S(s,x))\,ds,$$

and define $H:\mathbb{R}_+\times X\to\mathbb{R}_+$ so that $t\mapsto H(t,x)$ is the inverse of $t\mapsto S(t,x)$.

> I am interested in knowing if it would be possible to find some general sufficient conditions regarding $S$ and $\lambda$ under which $M:\mathbb{R}_+\times X\to X$, given by
>   $$M(t,x)=S(H(t,x),x),$$
>   has the flow property.

I have observed that $H$ should satisfy 
$$H(t+s,x)=H(t, S(H(s,x),x))+H(s,x).$$
It holds, for instance, if $X=\mathbb{R}$, $S(t,x)=xe^{t}$  and $\lambda(x)=|x|$. In this case we have $H(t,x)=\ln(1+t|x|^{-1}
)$ and $M$ is a semi-flow of the form $M(t,x)=x(1+t|x|^{-1})$.

Comment: I think the domain of $\lambda$ should be $X$, or at least contain the range of $X$. Additionally, the range of $L$ should be $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, thanks! It was a mistake, already corrected.